# VSC the copy line Down doesn't work and when i trie to edit the key combination it not resolving

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I try do copy down line with the shortcut : Ctrl + Shift + alt + DownArrow but it not working. I have a small keybord (65% => so i have to press the FN key to have the Down Arrow) and when i trie the combination keybinding by editing in VSC, the key down Arrow is not taken into account.
it like i press only "Ctrl + Shift + Alt".
The key arrow Down work well if i press only the combination FN + K.
observation: the FN +K give "Down" in the keybinding editor of VSC and not "DownArrow" by default in VSC.

Comment: you can use the keybind dialog to see which key combo's VSC recognizes. Use `Record Keys` button. Then you can find a key combo that works for your keyboard and create a new key bind for the copy-line-down and copy-line-up commands

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but one way around it is to put the cursor anywhere on the line and simply hit `ctrl + c` followed by `ctrl + v`. This will basically copy the whole line to the clipboard and paste it to a new line. The downside to this approach is that your existing clipboard will be overwritten.

Answer (score 5):

I also had the same issue and after a little fiddling around found the problem is Ubuntu 22.04 has default keyboard shortcut set for moving workspace down.
This shortcut is not even visible in keyboard shortcuts but it's still set.
To free your key combination follow the steps given below.

1. Goto Ubuntu Setting and go where all the keyboard shortcuts are listed. This interface has changed little bit in 22.04 but its in the same place still.
2. **Find any already disabled shortcut and try to set your desired key combination there like (ctrl+shift+alt+down arrow). Here it will actually show you which task is blocking up you key combination.**
3. After setting your combination to new shortcut just change it again and this time press backspace key this will unset the shortcut and free the  key combination.
4. Now you can set you combination in VS Code : ***File -> Preference -> Keyboard Shortcut -> Copy Line Down***.

In my case I set it to (ctrl+alt+down arrow) and similarly for copy up also instead of including shift key as well.

I hope this resolves you problem

Comment: I wanted to set the VS-Code shortcut to copy line-up/down to CTRL+ALT+UP/DOWN, but Ubuntu has the same keybinding for Move to Workspace Up/Down, which was something not even possible because Ubuntu has a horizontal layout for work spaces. In Ubuntu 22.04, one can only shift left/right to current workspace. Inside Settings>Keyboard>Shortcut>Navigation>Move to workspace on the left/right options were present, but options up/down were not present and still the shortcut keys were bound and cannot be used elsewhere.

Comment: Just applied the falsely bound shortcut to any shortcut, this replaced it from the original shortcut binding. And then i disabled the random shortcut and i was free to use the key-binding anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I use e.g. Ctrl + Shift + Alt + NumPadDownArrow

Hope that works for you

Comment: This works but the numpad is too far right :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but the following method worked for me.

My scenario is:

1. Create a new custom shortcut in the Ubuntu settings menu
2. Create a new command: "editor.action.copyLinesDownAction" and "editor.action.copyLinesUpAction".
3. Create a new custom shortcut: "Ctrl+Shift+Alt+DownArrow" and "Ctrl+Shift+Alt+UpArrow".
4. Ignore the warning message during the process of adding a new custom shortcut, it says that the shortcut is already in use.
5. After you finish adding a new custom shortcut, return to the custom shortcut menu you just created and select Remove.
6. Try the command again in VS Code.

Hopefully it will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick you can use to get the shortcut working. Add a custom keyboard shortcut with the keybinding `Shift+Ctrl+Alt+down`. This disables the gnome shortcut that uses the same keybinding. After saving the keybinding, remove it. The VSCode bindings will now work since the gnome binding stays disabled.

[image]